# Transpose arrayLists with .split(",")

Tags: java

I have a program reading in arrayLists and transposing it. The input file is
`C0 F0 D0 E0 G0 B0`
`C1 F1 D1 E1 G1 B1`
`C2 F2 D2 E2 G2 B2`
`C3 F3 D3 E3 G3 B3`
`C4 F4 D4 E4 G4 B4`
`C5 F5 D5 E5 G5 B5`
I want to know how to change the program so that the input is
`C0,F0,D0,E0,G0,B0`
`C1,F1,D1,E1,G1,B1`
`C2,F2,D2,E2,G2,B2`
`C3,F3,D3,E3,G3,B3`
`C4,F4,D4,E4,G4,B4`
`C5,F5,D5,E5,G5,B5`
So somewhere the .split(",") has to be used.
I'd also like to know how to make the program read in a general number of columns. So how 2-dimensional arrayLists have to be used? Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class list {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     FileOutputStream out; 
     PrintStream p; 

     try
     {
      File file = new File(args[0]);  
      String fileName= file.getName();
      int len = fileName.length();
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(fileName);
      sb.replace(len-4,len,".hr");
      out = new FileOutputStream(sb.toString());
      p = new PrintStream( out );


        try {
            List<String> column1 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            List<String> column2 = new ArrayList<String>();   
            List<String> column3 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            List<String> column4 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            List<String> column5 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            List<String> column6 = new ArrayList<String>(); 

            Scanner myfile = new Scanner(new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(args[0]))); 

            while (myfile.hasNext()) {          

                column1.add(myfile.next());     
                column2.add(myfile.next());     
                column3.add(myfile.next());
                column4.add(myfile.next());
                column5.add(myfile.next());
                column6.add(myfile.next());
            }

            myfile.close(); 

            p.println(column1);
            p.println(column2);
            p.println(column3);
            p.println(column4);
            p.println(column5);
            p.println(column6);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
      System.err.println ("Error writing to file");
      }

    } // End of MAIN


}
```

Comment: Oh my! Please format the text of your question a bit. You can mark up code blocks to make it look like code, see other questions for examples.

Comment: You should learn how to post formatted, properly indented code.

Comment: Please put your code inside a "code snippet" (the {} icon above the editor) and format it, so it becomes readable.

Comment: There's no way all that code is relevant to the problem you're having. Try to only include the necessary parts, huge runs of other people's code are intimidating.

Comment: Because your code is not properly formatted, not even you know what's going on inside.  You're repeatedly applying `transpose` to your array inside a double loop.

Comment: (You might notice a trend in the comments.)

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do isn't called the transpose - the transpose would be changing rows into columns and vice versa. It looks like you're just trying to extract the columns into a one-dimensional array. Something like this should do it:

```
    public static String[] transpose(String [][] a) {
        int r = a.length;
        int c = a[r - 1].length;

        String [] t = new String[r * c];
        for(int i = 0; i < c; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < r; ++j) {
                t[i * r + j] = a[j][i];
            }
        }
        return t;
    }
```

Please note how I have formatted my code.

**Edit:**

I see what you were trying to do with the transpose now. Without changing your code too much, this should work:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class SwapIO {

    public static String[][] transpose(String [][] a) {
        int r = a.length;
        int c = a[0].length;

        String [][] t = new String[c][r];
        for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                t[j][i] = a[i][j];
            }
        }
        return t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        FileOutputStream out; // declare a file output object
        PrintStream p; // declare a print stream object

        try
        {
            // Create a new file output stream
            // connected to "myfile.txt"
            File file = new File(args[0]);  
            String fileName= file.getName();
            int len = fileName.length();
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(fileName);
            sb.replace(len-4,len,".hr");
            out = new FileOutputStream(sb.toString());

            // Connect print stream to the output stream
            p = new PrintStream( out );

            //                                   p.println ("This is written to a file");
            Scanner sc = null;
            try {
                sc = new Scanner(new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(args[0])));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }

            try {
                //        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("array.txt"));
                Scanner input = new Scanner(new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(args[0])));
                int m = count(args[0]) + 1;
                int n = count(args[0]) + 1;
                int place;
                int string;
                String[][] a = new String[m][n];
                //                              while (input.hasNextLine()) {

                int row = 0;
                while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                    String txt = input.next();
                    String[] tmp = txt.split(",");
                    a[row++] = tmp;
                }

                String[][] transpose = transpose(a);

                for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                        try{//    System.out.println("number is ");
                            System.out.println(transpose[i][j]);
                        }
                        catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e) {
                            // e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                //                              }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println ("Error writing to file");
        }
    }

    public static int count(String filename) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
        try {
            byte[] c = new byte[1024];
            int count = 0;
            int readChars = 0;
            while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
                    if (c[i] == '\n')
                        ++count;
                }
            }
            return count;
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The transpose isn't really necessary, you could just loop through the input array differently after it's been populated with the file data, but I've left it in there in case you actually want the input to be transposed.

Comment: I have changed my question a little bit. Can someone help me?

Comment: I've updated my answer. By the way, if you want people to help you on here you should make it as easy as possible for them - that means not just applying 'code' formatting but to also indent your code correctly and only posting relevant code (as pointed out by several comments above).

Comment: java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:838)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1347)
 at SwapIO.main(SwapIO.java:59)

Comment: while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                    String txt = input.next();
                    String[] tmp = txt.split(",");
                    a[row++] = tmp;
                }

Comment: With this code I got the above error, which is the above loop. Maybe the a[row++] does not work outside this loop?

Comment: Take a look at your count method. It's counting the number of items in the first row of your text file; it should be returning the number of rows. You need to fix that method or you can get rid of it and work with a dynamic structure like an ArrayList instead of an array - then you don't have to worry about array sizes.